# Is it possible to select the previous similar text in Sublime?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu, sublimetext

In OSX, command + D will allow us to select the next similar text in sublime, but command + shift + D will duplicate the text. Is it possible to select the previous text? If so, what is the keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

You can `Find Previous` by using:

<kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>

Using (Shift + Command + G) will jump back to similar selected text, then you can tap (Command + D) to select multiples.